# How do i write this query in entity-framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a table (Items) with records in this format.

```
Name     | ProductId | Owner
Product1 | 1         | xx
Product2 | 2         | yy
Product1 | 1         | xx
Product3 | 3         | xx
Product3 | 3         | xx
Product3 | 3         | xx
Product4 | 4         | xx
Product2 | 2         | xx
Product5 | 5         | xx
```

I want to write entity framework query that will return the top 3 products, their names and Count. The result should look like this.

```
Result
Name: [Product3, Product2, Product1],
Count:[3, 2, 2]
```

I have checked other answers here on SO but still did not find something close to what i want. Note Name and Count returns a list of the top 3 respectively.

Comment: What about using linq GroupBy? Do you want to use linq?

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan, yes if returns the expected output

Comment: @InBetween answer seems ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code

```
var query = context
            .products
            .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .Take(3);

products.Select(p => new
{
    Name = query.Select(g => g.Key).ToList(),
    Count = query.Select(g => g.Count()).ToList(),
})
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Although I recommend that you get top 3 product with count together from database and then put it in different list, like this :

```
var products = context.products
            .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .Take(3)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count()
            })
            .ToList();
List<string> names = products.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
List<int> counts = products.Select(p => p.Count).ToList();
```

Comment: You should be ordering by descending order, otherwise you are taking the bottom 3 products.

Comment: @InBetween you're right, thanks. I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you @Arvin, just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
products.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .Take(3);
```